# unit converting program using python tkinter (trouble with creating windows)

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
def ftm(feet):
    return feet*0.305
def mft(meter):
    return round((meters/0.305),3)
def choose():
    if lol=="ft":
        feet = StringVar()
        meters = StringVar()
        rest=Tk()
        f3=Frame(rest)
        f3.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
        f3.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        f3.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        feet_entry = Entry(f3, width=7, textvariable=feet)
        feet_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
        Label(f3, textvariable=meters).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
        Button(f3, text="Calculate", command=ftm).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)
        Label(f3, text="feet").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W)
        Label(f3, text="is equal to").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
        Label(f3, text="meters").grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)
    elif lol=="m":
        foot = StringVar()
        meter = StringVar()
        pepp=Tk()
        f4=Frame(pepp)
        f4.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
        f4.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        f4.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        meter_entry = Entry(f4, width=7, textvariable=meter)
        meter_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
        Label(f4, textvariable=foot).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
        Button(f4, text="Calculate", command=mft).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)
        Label(f4, text="meters").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W)
        Label(f4, text="is equal to").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
        Label(f4, text="feet").grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)
    else:
        rino=Tk()
        f5=Frame(rino)
        Label(f5, text="ERROR!").grid(column=1, row=1)


global lol
rip=Tk()
f2=Frame(rip)
f2.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
f2.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
f2.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
c1=Label(f2, text="feet to meter or meter to feet?")
c1.grid(row=0,column=0)
c2=Label(f2, text="type ft for feet to meter, type m for meter to feet")
c2.grid(row=1,column=0)
lol=StringVar()
choice=Entry(f2,width=4, textvariable=lol)
choice.grid(row=2, column=0)
b1=Button(f2, text="Confirm",command=choose)
b1.grid(row=3,column=0)
```

I'm trying to first create a choosing window. Then create different windows for different choices. The choosing window is perfectly fine, however, after I hit confirm, the only thing I can get is a empty window. I really don't know how to create a window using frame. I'm still a beginner of python. Plz help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous problems with your code, but to answer the question you asked, the blank window is because function `choose()` isn't checking the value of `lol` properly. To get the current value of a `StringVar` widget, you need to call its `get()` method — so change the first if from:

```
    if lol=="ft":
```

to

```
    if lol.get()=="ft":
```

and the following `elif` from:

```
    elif lol=="m":
```

to

```
    elif lol.get()=="m":
```

Then a blank window won't be displayed unless you type in something unrecognized (i.e. something that wasn't `ft` or `m`). To fix that, add the second line shown below in the `else` clause.

```
        f5=Frame(rino)
        f5.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S)) # <- need to add this line
```

**Update**

Below is a heavily revised version of your code which I think addresses the additional questions you asked in the comments. It also closely follows the [PEP8 Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which is especially important when other folks have to read your code in order to help you because it generally clarifies what's going on.

```
from tkinter import *

def ftm(feet):
    return feet * 0.305

def mtf(meters):
    return meters / 0.305

def convert(amount, func, result):
    value = func(float(amount.get()))
    result.set(round((value), 3))

def choose():
    choice = lol.get()
    if choice == "ft":
        feet = StringVar()
        meters = StringVar()
        rest = Toplevel()
        f3 = Frame(rest)
        f3.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
        f3.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        f3.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        feet_entry = Entry(f3, width=7, textvariable=feet)
        feet_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
        Label(f3, text="feet").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W)
        Label(f3, text="is equal to").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
        Label(f3, textvariable=meters).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
        Label(f3, text="meters").grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)
        Button(f3,
               text="Calculate",
               command=lambda a=feet_entry, f=ftm, r=meters: convert(a, f, r)
              ).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)
    elif choice == "m":
        meters = StringVar()
        feet = StringVar()
        pepp = Toplevel()
        f4 = Frame(pepp)
        f4.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
        f4.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        f4.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        meter_entry = Entry(f4, width=7, textvariable=meters)
        meter_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))
        Label(f4, text="meters").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W)
        Label(f4, text="is equal to").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
        Label(f4, textvariable=feet).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
        Label(f4, text="feet").grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)
        Button(f4,
               text="Calculate",
               command=lambda a=meter_entry, f=mtf, r=feet: convert(a, f, r)
              ).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)
    else:
        rino = Toplevel()
        f5 = Frame(rino)
        f5.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
        Label(f5, text="ERROR!").grid(column=1, row=1)

rip = Tk()
f2 = Frame(rip)
f2.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
f2.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
f2.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
c1=Label(f2, text="feet to meter or meter to feet?")
c1.grid(row=0, column=0)
c2=Label(f2, text='type "ft" for feet to meter, type "m" for meter to feet')
c2.grid(row=1, column=0)
lol = StringVar()
choice=Entry(f2, width=4, textvariable=lol)
choice.grid(row=2, column=0)
b1=Button(f2, text="Confirm", command=choose)
b1.grid(row=3, column=0)

rip.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, it worked. Then i tried it, it showed : ftm() missing 1 required positional argument: 'feet' , so i removed "feet" from ftm(feet), then i put it under global, it showed  name 'feet' is not defined, can you help me with this as well?

Comment: If my answer worked, you should accept it. The `missing 1 required positional argument error` is being caused by the `command=ftm` in the `Button(f3, text="Calculate", command=ftm).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)` statement since it specifies that when the button is clicked, to call `ftm()` with no arguments. You need to create a new function to specify which first gets the current value of the `feet_entry` widget, converts that to a numeric value (using `float()` or `int()`), and then calls `ftm(value)`. This same new function could also display the returned result somewhere afterwards.

Comment: i used value=float(feet_entry.get()) and command=ftm(value) but it says: ValueError: could not convert string to float:  sorry for having so many questions, but please help me.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with what you used. I suggested making a new function to use as the `command=` argument. The tricky part is passing it the variables it needs to do the work. This can be accomplished by using a `lambda` function as a go-between and giving it default arguments. This is illustrated in the update I've added to my original answer.